# Avoid inner loop while iterating through nested data (performance improvement)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am working with a large dataset (1 million + rows) and am tasked with counting up each truthy value for each ID and generating a new dict.

The solution I came up with works, but does very poor in regards to performance.

I have a dictionary as follow:

```
  "data": {
    "employees": [
      {
        "id": 274,
        "report": true
      },
      {
        "id": 274,
        "report": false
      },
      {
        "id": 276,
        "report": true
      },
      {
        "id": 276,
        "report": true
      },
      {
        "id": 278,
        "report": true
      },
      {
        "id": 278,
        "report": false
      }
    ]
  }
```

I am looking to create a new dictionary with each individual employee ID with a count of each true value.

Something like this:

```
{274: {'id': 274, 'count': 1}, 276: {'id': 276, 'count': 2}, 278: {'id': 278, 'count': 1}}
```

My current code:

```
        final_dict = {}

        for employee in result["data"]["employees"]:
            if employee["id"] not in final_dict.keys():
                final_dict[employee["id"]] = {"id": employee["id"]}
                grouped_results = [res for res in result["data"]["employees"] if
                                   employee["id"] == res['id']]
                final_dict[employee["id"]]["count"] = len(
                    [res for res in grouped_results if res["report"]]
                )

                return final_dict
```

This does what it needs to do, but with the amount of data that is being processed it does very poorly.

I am looking for some advice on how to avoid the multiple loops, in order to improve performance. Any advice helps!

Comment: `{274: {'id': 274, 'count': 1}}` This structure seems needlessly complicated.  Why do you need the sub-dictionary at all?  The `'id'` is just a duplicate of the outer dictionary key.  Why not just use `{274: 1, 276: 2, 278: 1, ...}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to make multiple passes, just accumulate as you go so it is linear time not quadratic

```
result = {}

for employee in input_dict["data"]["employees"]:
    _id = employee["id"]
    if _id not in result:
        # note id is being added redundantly maybe rethink this
        result[_id] = dict(id=_id, count=0)
    result[_id]["count"] += employee["report"]
```

Answer (score 2):

With [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) function:

```
report_counts = {}
for employee in result["data"]["employees"]:
    d = report_counts.setdefault(employee['id'], {'id': employee['id'], 'count': 0})
    d['count'] += employee['report']

print(report_counts)
```

---

```
{274: {'id': 274, 'count': 1}, 276: {'id': 276, 'count': 2}, 278: {'id': 278, 'count': 1}}
```

Comment: One thing I like about this solution is that the variable `d` while adding clarity can be taken out making the code inside the for loop a single line.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```py
dct = {
    "data": {
        "employees": [
            {"id": 274, "report": True},
            {"id": 274, "report": False},
            {"id": 276, "report": True},
            {"id": 276, "report": True},
            {"id": 278, "report": True},
            {"id": 278, "report": False},
        ]
    }
}

out = {}
for d in dct['data']['employees']:
    out[d['id']] = out.get(d['id'], 0) + d['report']

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{274: 1, 276: 2, 278: 1}
```

---

To convert it to your output:

```
out = {k: {'id': k, 'count': v} for k, v in out.items()}
```

Prints:

```
{274: {'id': 274, 'count': 1}, 276: {'id': 276, 'count': 2}, 278: {'id': 278, 'count': 1}}
```

Comment: I actually like your output. Much cleaner. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you could use the Counter class from collections:

```
source = {
"data": {
    "employees": [
      {
        "id": 274,
        "report": True
      },
      {
        "id": 274,
        "report": False
      },
      {
        "id": 276,
        "report": True
      },
      {
        "id": 276,
        "report": True
      },
      {
        "id": 278,
        "report": True
      },
      {
        "id": 278,
        "report": False
      }
    ]
  }
}

from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(e["id"] for e in source["data"]["employees"] if e["report"])
result = {i:{"id":i,"count":c} for i,c in counts.items()}
```

output:

```
print(result)
{274: {'id': 274, 'count': 1}, 276: {'id': 276, 'count': 2}, 278: {'id': 278, 'count': 1}}

print(counts)
Counter({276: 2, 274: 1, 278: 1})
```